# Replace highcharts with images for report?

Tags: highcharts

I have about 100 charts I want to export to a printable report. It's to slow to have 100 charts in Internet Explorer. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Is it just 100 charts or 100 charts with text? If you want to export each chart as a single image you can use batch export if you run your own export server (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server). If you want to interleave with text then maybe generating a page with all your items and exporting to PDF from within the browser (IE is slower here but any browser might be slow depending on how much data is in each chart).

Answer (score 0):

You can send POST requests to export server in order to export all of your charts without actually rendering them in the browser.

```
const options = {
  chart: {},
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ]
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    type: 'column'
  }]
}
const data = {
    options: JSON.stringify(options),
    filename: 'test.png',
    type: 'image/png',
    async: true
}
const exportUrl = 'https://export.highcharts.com/'
$.post(exportUrl, data, function(data) {
    const imageUrl = exportUrl + data
    const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL
    document.querySelector("#image").src = imageUrl
})

// You can uncomment in order to render chart
// const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/28098mfj/